# Problems Setting Up 580EX II as Master, 430EX as slave

Tags: canon, strobist, strobes

I'm trying to use my 580EX II as a master and trigger via wireless remote. When not in Master mode, the 580EX II triggers remotely. However, once I put it in Master mode, it no longer works. Thus, I can't setup master/slave.

Here's a photo of the settings of the 2 lights:

[Image and video hosting by TinyPic http://i56.tinypic.com/f41pqw.jpg](http://i56.tinypic.com/f41pqw.jpg)

Any ideas what is wrong? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 580exII needs to be attached to your camera to be able to trigger things remotely as a master.

If you want to trigger both, you need to have another 580exII, ST-E2 wireless transmitter or use the built in transmitter that comes with the 60D or 7D.